# search in schema of a dataframe using pyspark

Tags: scala, dataframe, pyspark, schema

I have a set of dataframes, dfs, with different schema, for example:

```
      root
       |-- A_id: string (nullable = true)
       |-- b_cd: string (nullable = true)
       |-- c_id: integer (nullable = true)
       |-- d_info: struct (nullable = true)
       |    |-- eid: string (nullable = true)
       |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
       |-- l: array (nullable = true)
       |    |-- m: struct (containsNull = true)
       |    |    |-- n: string (nullable = true)
       |    |    |-- o: string (nullable = true)
        ..........
```

I want to check if, for example, "oid" is given in one of the column (here under d_info column). How can I search inside a schema for a set of dataframes and distinguish them. Pyspark or Scala suggestion are both helpful. Thank you

Comment: what is your expected result? do you need the dateframe name, root column names, or just a boolean value if field name exists in a dataframe?

Comment: Root column name or basically the whole path from the root to the expected node. For example, in my example for "n" the result would be l=>m=>n

Comment: one way is to parse *df.dtypes*, this gives you a list of `(col_name, col_type)`, you can write a regex to check if col_type contains the "oid" (for example `ptn = r'[<,]oid:'`), if matches, then get the *df_name*+*root_col_name*. to retrieve the full path, you can probably parse df.schema.jsonValue() which is a Python object with nested dicts/lists, or df.schema.json() which returns the same information in a JSON string. all these become a pure Python/Scala programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary/map of [node , root to node path] could be created for DataFame StructType (including nested StructType) using a recursive function.

```
val df = spark.read.json("nested_data.json")
val path = searchSchema(df.schema, "n", "root")

def searchSchema(schema: StructType, key: String, path: String): String = {
  val paths = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
  addPaths(schema, path, paths)
  paths(key)
}

def addPaths(schema: StructType, path: String, paths: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]): Unit = {
for (field <- schema.fields) {
  val _path = s"$path.${field.name}"
  paths += (field.name -> _path)
  field.dataType match {
    case structType: StructType => addPaths(structType, _path, paths)
    case arrayType: ArrayType => addPaths(arrayType.elementType.asInstanceOf[StructType], _path, paths)
    case _ => //donothing
  }
 }
}
```

Input and output

```
Input = {"A_id":"A_id","b_cd":"b_cd","c_id":1,"d_info":{"eid":"eid","oid":"oid"},"l":[{"m":{"n":"n1","o":"01"}},{"m":{"n":"n2","o":"02"}}]}

Output = Map(n -> root.l.m.n, b_cd -> root.b_cd, d_info -> root.d_info, m -> root.l.m, oid -> root.d_info.oid, c_id -> root.c_id, l -> root.l, o -> root.l.m.o, eid -> root.d_info.eid, A_id -> root.A_id)
```